# How to create two events in unbalanced panel data?

Tags: r, dplyr

My aim is to create two variables (`unemployed` and `inactive`) in an unbalanced panel data that shows are based on certain events. The status variable is `0= employed`, `1= unemployed` and `2=inactive`. First, the `unemployed` variable that i would like to create shows a transition from only 0 to 1. The `inactive` variable that i would like to create shows a transition from only 0 to 2. If an individual starts with 1 or 2 on the first observation (e.g., like individual with `id` 6), these are not considered as events. Finally we can see that individuals might drop one or more waves, however, this should be irrelevant to the variables we want to create. In other words, our individual with `id` 1 has dropped `wave` 3 and 4, but then came back in `wave` 5 and we considered it as an `unemployed` event.

Here is the expected output:

```
    id wave status    unemployed inactive
1   1    1      0          0        0
2   1    2      0          0        0
3   1    5      1          1        0
4   2    1      0          0        0
5   2    2      0          0        0
6   3    1      0          0        0
7   3    2      2          0        1
8   3    3      1          0        0
9   4    1      0          0        0
10  4    2      2          0        1
11  4    4      0          0        0
12  5    1      2          0        0
13  5    3      0          0        0
14  5    5      1          1        0
15  5    6      1          0        0
16  6    1      1          0        0
17  6    3      2          0        1
18  6    5      2          0        0
```

Here is the data:

```
df=structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 6, 6, 6), wave = c(1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 
    3, 5, 6, 1, 3, 5), status = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
    2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df  |>
  group_by(id)  |>
  mutate(
    unemployed = (status == 1) & (lag(status, default = status[1]) == 0),
    inactive = (status == 2) & (lag(status, default = status[1]) != 2),
  )

# A tibble: 18 x 5
# Groups:   id [6]
#       id  wave status unemployed inactive
#    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>
#  1     1     1      0 FALSE      FALSE
#  2     1     2      0 FALSE      FALSE
#  3     1     5      1 TRUE       FALSE
#  4     2     1      0 FALSE      FALSE
#  5     2     2      0 FALSE      FALSE
#  6     3     1      0 FALSE      FALSE
#  7     3     2      2 FALSE      TRUE
#  8     3     3      1 FALSE      FALSE
#  9     4     1      0 FALSE      FALSE
# 10     4     2      2 FALSE      TRUE
# 11     4     4      0 FALSE      FALSE
# 12     5     1      2 FALSE      FALSE
# 13     5     3      0 FALSE      FALSE
# 14     5     5      1 TRUE       FALSE
# 15     5     6      1 FALSE      FALSE
# 16     6     1      1 FALSE      FALSE
# 17     6     3      2 FALSE      TRUE
# 18     6     5      2 FALSE      FALSE
```

I have left them as `logical` rather than `numeric` variables as I think that is the appropriate data type in this case, but you can change that by wrapping the relevant part in `as.numeric()`, e.g. `unemployed = as.numeric((status == 1) & (lag(status, default = status[1]) == 0))`.

I have assumed that:

1. A person is unemployed only if they transition from being employed.
2. A person is inactive if they move to being inactive from being employed or unemployed.
3. A person should have the transition flag set to `TRUE` in the first period if they are inactive or unemployed in the first period - that is what `default = status[1]` is doing.

Also just for fun here is a `data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)

dt  <- setDT(df)

dt[, 
   `:=` (
    unemployed = (status == 1) & (shift(status, type = "lag", fill = status[1]) == 0), 
    inactive = (status == 2) & (shift(status, type = "lag", fill = status[1]) != 2)
   ), 
   keyby = id
]
```

This should be faster if your data set is very large.